# How to connect HBase and Spark using Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hbase, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an embarrassingly parallel task for which I use Spark to distribute the computations. These computations are in Python, and I use PySpark to read and preprocess the data. The input data to my task is stored in HBase. Unfortunately, I've yet to find a satisfactory (i.e., easy to use and scalable) way to read/write HBase data from/to Spark using Python.

What I've explored previously:

- Connecting from within my Python processes using `happybase`. This package allows connecting to HBase from Python by using HBase's Thrift API. This way, I basically skip Spark for data reading/writing and am missing out on potential HBase-Spark optimizations. Read speeds seem reasonably fast, but write speeds are slow. This is currently my best solution.
- Using SparkContext's `newAPIHadoopRDD` and `saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset` that make use of HBase's MapReduce interface. Examples for this were once included in the Spark code base ([see here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ed9d80385486cd39a84a689ef467795262af919a/examples/src/main/python/hbase_inputformat.py)). However, these are now considered outdated in favor of HBase's Spark bindings ([see here](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/a680562a6f87a03a00f71bad1c424267ae75c641)). I've also found this method to be slow and cumbersome (for reading, writing worked well), for example as the strings returned from `newAPIHadoopRDD` had to be parsed and transformed in various ways to end up with the Python objects I wanted. It also only supported a single column at a time.

Alternatives that I'm aware of:

- I'm currently using Cloudera's CDH and version 5.7.0 offers `hbase-spark` ([CDH release notes](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_rn_new_in_cdh_57.html#concept_hzs_qzh_cv), and [a detailed blog post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/08/apache-spark-comes-to-apache-hbase-with-hbase-spark-module/)). This module (formerly known as `SparkOnHBase`) will officially be a part of HBase 2.0. Unfortunately, this wonderful solution seems to work only with Scala/Java.
- Huawei's [Spark-SQL-on-HBase](https://github.com/Huawei-Spark/Spark-SQL-on-HBase) / [Astro](https://github.com/HuaweiBigData/astro) (I don't see a difference between the two...). It does not look as robust and well-supported as I'd like my solution to be.

Comment: Not sure how CDH distributed the hbase-spark connector. The write path trace looks to me it uses old code base, which does not support write path.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution?Whoever merged that PR that removed all the existing working examples from the spark/examples folder did a big disservice to pyspark users.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found [this comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-15225?focusedCommentId=15135626&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15135626) by one of the makers of `hbase-spark`, which seems to suggest there is a way to use PySpark to query HBase using Spark SQL.

And indeed, [the pattern described here](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_sparksql_dataframes) can be applied to query HBase with Spark SQL using PySpark, as the following example shows:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext()
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

data_source_format = 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark'

df = sc.parallelize([('a', '1.0'), ('b', '2.0')]).toDF(schema=['col0', 'col1'])

# ''.join(string.split()) in order to write a multi-line JSON string here.
catalog = ''.join("""{
    "table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"testtable"},
    "rowkey":"key",
    "columns":{
        "col0":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
        "col1":{"cf":"cf", "col":"col1", "type":"string"}
    }
}""".split())


# Writing
df.write\
.options(catalog=catalog)\  # alternatively: .option('catalog', catalog)
.format(data_source_format)\
.save()

# Reading
df = sqlc.read\
.options(catalog=catalog)\
.format(data_source_format)\
.load()
```

I've tried `hbase-spark-1.2.0-cdh5.7.0.jar` (as distributed by Cloudera) for this, but ran into trouble (`org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.DefaultSource does not allow create table as select` when writing, `java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get` when reading). As it turns out, the present version of CDH does not include the changes to `hbase-spark` that allow Spark SQL-HBase integration.

What *does* work for me is the `shc` Spark package, found [here](https://github.com/hortonworks/shc). The only change I had to make to the above script is to change:

```
data_source_format = 'org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase'
```

Here's how I submit the above script on my CDH cluster, following the example from the `shc` README:

```
spark-submit --packages com.hortonworks:shc:1.0.0-1.6-s_2.10 --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/ --files /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml example.py
```

Most of the work on `shc` seems to already be merged into the `hbase-spark` module of HBase, for release in version 2.0. With that, Spark SQL querying of HBase is possible using the above-mentioned pattern (see:  https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_sparksql_dataframes for details). My example above shows what it looks like for PySpark users.

Finally, a caveat: my example data above has only strings. Python data conversion is not supported by `shc`, so I had problems with integers and floats not showing up in HBase or with weird values.

Comment: can i use this for managing big-data  with more than 1 million Row?

Comment: Also, what is the parameter --files for? What does the value specified to it mean? Is it optional to have this parameter/value pair?

Comment: @bikashg, see: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/38482/loading-local-file-to-apache-spark.html