# How to connect from pyspark to hbase

Tags: python, apache-spark, hbase, pyspark

I have two clusters in azure, one for spark 2.0 and another for hbase. I can fill and use the hbase perfectly, now I want to connect the spark to the hbase and do some calculations. I would like to use python as I don't know scala.

My first questions is: What's the best way to do it? spark -> hive -> hbase or spark directly to hbase?

Could I have a good examples for inserting and querying?

Thanks?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to go through hive.   wrong with the Spark Hbase Connector?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. My problem is that I can not find a connector for python with good examples. Maybe I am not having a good day googling

Comment: Yeah, I only found scala examples. There are hbase python libraries, though, so I assume you only want spark for the parallelism

Comment: Well, maybe it is a good time to learn scala. What do you think?

Comment: Ha. The spark api is really easy to translate. If you know java and understand python functional programming, it's a nice language. I started learning myself a few months ago

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470114/how-to-connect-hbase-and-spark-using-python

Answer (score 0):

If you're cool with Spark to HBase directly via the Spark-to-HBase connector, Zhan Zhang has a pretty good blog post at http://hortonworks.com/blog/spark-hbase-dataframe-based-hbase-connector/ providing examples.

HTH!