# Error while writing to HBase Table using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write to hbase table using pySpark. So far, I could able to read the data from hbase. but getting exception when writing to hbase table.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *

properties = {
  "instanceId" : "hbase",
  "zookeepers" : "10-x-x-x.local:2181,10-x-x-x.local:2181,10-x-x-x.local:2181",
  "hbase.columns.mapping" : "KEY_FIELD STRING :key, A STRING c:a, B STRING c:b",
  "hbase.use.hbase.context" : False,
  "hbase.config.resources" : "file:///etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml",
  "hbase.table"  : "t"
}
spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("hbaseWrite")\
        .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

#I am able to read the data successfully.
#df = spark.read.format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark")\
#    .options( **properties)\
#    .load()

data = [("3","DATA 3 A", "DATA 3 B")]
columns = ['KEY_FIELD','A','B']
cSchema = StructType([StructField(columnName, StringType()) for columnName in columns])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=cSchema)
df.write\
      .options( **properties)\
      .mode('overwrite').format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark").save()
```

Executing Command in the following format:

```
spark2-submit --master local[*] write_to_hbase.py
```

Spark Version: 2.2.0.cloudera1 (I can't change my spark version)
HBase Version: 1.2.0-cdh5.12.0 (But I can change my HBase Version)

**Note:** I have added the hbase jars to spark2 jar folder and I ve added to following dependent jars to the spark2 jar folder.

1. spark-core_2.11-1.6.1.jar
2. htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar
3. scala-library-2.9.1.jar

Error :

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.save.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.DefaultSource does not allow create table as select.
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:476)
```

I've tried multiple suggestions but nothing worked. It might be a duplicate question, but I have no other option to find a answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470114/how-to-connect-hbase-and-spark-using-python/38575095

Comment: @AniketKulkarni: If i change the datasource and format and execute the code, code is stuck in-between : **:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0**

Comment: @AniketKulkarni: repo not available . https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/hortonworks/shc/1.0.0-1.6-s_2.10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by compiling the git repo https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc and put the shc jar in the spark jar folder.  and followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470114/how-to-connect-hbase-and-spark-using-python/38575095) suggessted by @Aniket Kulkarni

the final code looks something like this,

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *

properties = {
  "instanceId" : "hbase",
  "zookeepers" : "10-x-x-x.local:2181,10-x-x-x.local:2181,10-x-x-x.local:2181",
  "hbase.columns.mapping" : "KEY_FIELD STRING :key, A STRING c:a, B STRING c:b",
  "hbase.use.hbase.context" : False,
  "hbase.config.resources" : "file:///etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml",
  "hbase.table"  : "test_table"
}
spark = SparkSession.builder\
        .appName("hbaseWrite")\
        .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
catalog = ''.join("""{
    "table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"test_table"}
    "rowkey":"key",
    "columns":{
        "KEY_FIELD":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
        "A":{"cf":"c", "col":"a", "type":"string"},
        "B":{"cf":"c", "col":"b", "type":"string"}
    }
}""".split())


data = [("3","DATA 3 A", "DATA 3 B")]
columns = ['KEY_FIELD','A','B']
cSchema = StructType([StructField(columnName, StringType()) for columnName in columns])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=cSchema)
df.write\
      .options(catalog=catalog)\
      .options( **properties)\
      .mode('overwrite').format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase").save()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Cloudera distribution` then Hard Luck there is no official way to write to `HBASE` using `PYSAPRK`. This has been confirmed by `Cloudera support Team`.

But if you are using `Hortonworks` and if you have `spark 2.0` then the below link should get you started.

[Pyspark to Hbase write](http://blog.manugarri.com/hdfs-vs-hbase-in-pyspark-2-0/)

Comment: can you provide the link Cloudera support team confirmation?

Comment: @AdaPongaya Sorry, I cannot do that as it is internal documentation. It was posted in Case notes of the support case raised by my team at work