# Unexpected end-of-input exception when writing to hbase using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hbase, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write DataFrames to HBase using Pyspark.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext()
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

data_source_format = 'org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase'

df = sc.parallelize([('a', '1.0'), ('b', '2.0')]).toDF(schema=['col0', 'col1'])

catalog = ''.join("""{
    "table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"testtable"},
    "rowkey":"key",
    "columns":{
        "col0":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
        "col1":{"cf":"cf", "col":"col1", "type":"string"}
    }
}""".split())


df.write.options(catalog=catalog).format(data_source_format).save()
```

Executing Command in the following format:

```
sudo spark-submit --packages com.hortonworks:shc-core:1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/  --files /home/chenxx/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml sogou4.py
```

Spark version : 2.3.0 Hadoop version: 2.7.6 HBase version: 1.1.5 Scala version: 2.11.6

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chenxx/PycharmProjects/SoGou/sogou4.py", line 52, in <module>
    df.write.options(catalog = catalog1).format(data_source_format).save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 701, in save
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
**py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o61.save.
: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for OBJECT (from [Source: {"table":{"namespace":"default","name":"testtable"},"rowkey":"key","columns":{"col0":{"cf":"rowkey","col":"key","type":"string"},"col1":{"cf":"cf","col":"col1","type":"string"}}; line: 1, column: 0])
 at [Source: {"table":{"namespace":"default","name":"testtable"},"rowkey":"key","columns":{"col0":{"cf":"rowkey","col":"key","type":"string"},"col1":{"cf":"cf","col":"col1","type":"string"}}; line: 1, column: 355]**
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1581)
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be? I would appreciate it if there were any suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Why you are passing json to `options` function.

Comment: Code comes from this answer：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470114/how-to-connect-hbase-and-spark-using-python

Comment: Can you check what is the output of catalog variable, Is it valid json?

Comment: Sorry.. I am a novice. Can you tell me how to check if it is a valid json?

Comment: There in so many online tool available to validate json.
http://json.parser.online.fr/