# Force spark to use more executors, one per partition

Tags: java, apache-spark, hbase

Spark is executing too many partitions within a single task, instead of distributing it.

We are ingesting fairly large volumes of data from HBase into a Spark dataset.

Due to incompatibility we are unable to use HBase-Spark and have resorted to using the basic JavaAPI client for HBase.

To help parallelize the ingest from HBase we placed the "startRows" into a dataset, re-partitioned the dataset to give 16 partitions, each containing 4 start rows.

We then used mapPartitions() to query the 4 start rows and return an iterator of the actual row data.

It does result in all rows being fetched, however even though we are sure the data is uniformly distributed between those start rows Spark insists on moving most of the partitions to 3 or 4 executors, instead of 16.

I'm fairly sure this is because Spark is unaware of the actual data we are loading and is optimizing souly on the startRows in the dataset.

Is there anyway to force spark to execute these as one task, one executor, per partition?

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
for(int salt=0; salt<maxSalt; salt++) { // maxSalt=64
   keys.add( extractStartRow( mainKey, String.valueOf(salt));
}
Dataset<String> saltSeed = sparkSession.createDataset(keys, 
Encoders.STRING());

int partitions = 16;

saltRange = saltRange.repartition(partitions);

Dataset<Results> = saltRange.mapPartitions(new Ingestor(mainKey), Encoders.bean(Results.class));

// Ingestor function, does the actual read from Hbase for the given salted start row.
```

We would like to find a way to get more tasks/executors working on the 
problem of reading from HBase.  Whatever we try, Spark reduces the workload down to only a few executors.  The rest get no partitions and no data to ingest.  The active executors take hours.

Comment: This may or may not help, but using pyspark, I increase the number of executor cores to use when I configure/launch spark:
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '8g'), ('spark.executor.cores', '3'), ('spark.cores.max', '3'), ('spark.driver.memory','8g')])

Comment: It's odd, as Spark does create 16 tasks, however about 13 of them have 0 rows in them.  Opening the executors that do get tasks with data I can see them sequentially running through dozens of salts, but this takes over an hour. :(
I will try forcing the number of executors to 16 and see what happens.

Comment: To clarify, you cannot use the method they say here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470114/how-to-connect-hbase-and-spark-using-python

Seems like they got around using hbase-spark by defining the data_source_format variable and passing it as an option. Did you try that?

Comment: The issue with SparkHbase is that in Spark 2.2 the calls made to the Hadoop user credential method getCurrentUserCredentials() has changed  prototype, but SparkHbase has not been updated and so fails with Method Not Found.  We spoke to our vendor who confirmed that even if we did hack it to work they said SparkHbase was not supported.  Thanks for the help though.